# Pandas inserting list as a cell value causes ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where a column's values are lists. I initialize the column thusly:

`df["My List"] = [[] for _ in range(len(df))]`

Then, in a loop, I compute a list value and assign it to a specific cell like so:

```
for i in range(1, df.shape[0]):
    idx_cur = df.index[i]
    ...
    cell_value = list(some_set)
    df.loc[idx_cur, "My List"] = cell_value
    ...
```

This throws:
`ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable`

The error is at the line `df.loc[idx_cur, "My List"] = cell_value`.
I get the exact same issue with `df.at`. Any thoughts?

Comment: there might be duplicate index, so `df.loc[idx_cur, 'My List']` is a series?

Comment: Not sure what causes this, but a workaround would be to use `.extend` like so: `df.loc[idx_cur, "My List"].extend(cell_value)`

Comment: FWIW, storing lists in columns makes the data pretty tedious/difficult to work with, and foregoes all the benefits of broadcasting and vectorization.

Comment: It's a well known "issue", but keep in mind that DataFrames are **not** designed to store lists.

Comment: Also, it is a lot easier to compute the entire column (as a list of list), then update it like you did with initialization. Pandas is designed that way.

Comment: @ddejohn: I understand the difficulty bit. I have a situation where I have to compare lists of items in a time series and bring out items that did not continue. The whole analysis is in Pandas, so don't want to use another tool for just this use case. I'll try the `extend` thing.

Comment: @QuangHoang: Index is not dupliated. `print(df.index.duplicated(keep="first"))` prints out a `list` of all `False`